# Graphing the representation of an iterated integral

Tags: calculus, 3d, iterated-integrals

We have to consider the integral of $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x^2} \int_{0}^{1-x}f(x,y,z)dzdydx$$

First we're told to graph the region of integration, so I started that but I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing. I end up with something that looks like a slim triangular slice of a cone, but I don't know if it's correct. Is it?

Comment: Formatting help: try `$\int_{lower}^{upper}f(x)dx$`.

Comment: the integral doesn't represent a surface. Assuming $f$ has units of density, then the integral represents the total amount of "stuff" in a volume.